# Merge List of maps updating values

Tags: elixir

I am trying to merge a list of dictionaries. Every dictionary in the list is nested and I need to sum the values on every element in the list. For example;

```
samples = [
  %{team1: %{a: 5, f: 0, n_games: 1}, team2: %{a: 0, f: 2, n_games: 1}},
  %{team1: %{a: 1, f: 2, n_games: 1}, team2: %{a: 4, f: 3, n_games: 1}}
]
```

Would need to return

```
%{team1: %{a: 6, f: 2, n_games: 2}, team2: %{a: 4, f: 5, n_games: 2}}
```

I would love to share any code I have, but I honestly don't have anything to share since I don't know the approach to these kind of problems in Elixir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Enum.reduce/2` and `Map.merge/3`. In `Map.merge/3`, the callback should add the three fields of both the values.

```
samples = [
  %{team1: %{a: 5, f: 0, n_games: 1}, team2: %{a: 0, f: 2, n_games: 1}},
  %{team1: %{a: 1, f: 2, n_games: 1}, team2: %{a: 4, f: 3, n_games: 1}}
]

samples
|> Enum.reduce(fn x, acc ->
  Map.merge(x, acc, fn _key, %{a: a1, f: f1, n_games: ng1}, %{a: a2, f: f2, n_games: ng2} ->
    %{a: a1 + a2, f: f1 + f2, n_games: ng1 + ng2}
  end)
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
%{team1: %{a: 6, f: 2, n_games: 2}, team2: %{a: 4, f: 5, n_games: 2}}
```

If you don't want to hardcode the list of keys in the map and just want to add all the values, you can do this instead:

```
|> Enum.reduce(fn x, acc ->
  Map.merge(x, acc, fn _key, map1, map2 ->
    for {k, v1} <- map1, into: %{}, do: {k, v1 + map2[k]}
  end)
end)
```